# how to make quick.db read async

Tags: node.js, quick.db

I want to make this read calls async. It should output to the console 'finish' and then 'done'.

But the script wait first to finish the loop. Why it's not working?

```
const db = require('quick.db');
 
var balance = null;
var items = null;

final();

console.log('finish');

async function final() {
    var res = await test();
    console.log('done');
}

async function test() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for(var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
                balance = db.get('userInfo.balance') // -> 1000
                items =  db.get('userInfo.items') // ['Sword', 'Watch']
    }
    resolve(true);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I have just copied and pasted your code and it works just the way you described it. It prints 'finish' and then 'done'. I'm not sure what's your question. However, I have a question about your code: Why would you use async and implicitly return a new Promise?

In addition to the above, you're trying to read some values from the db and they have not been set previously. I edited a bit your code:

```js
const db = require('quick.db');

var balance = null;
var items = null;

db.set('userInfo', { difficulty: 'Easy' });
db.add('userInfo.balance', 1000);
db.push('userInfo.items', 'Sword');
db.push('userInfo.items', 'Watch');

final();

console.log('finish');

async function final() {
    var res = await test();
    console.log(`Balance: ${balance} | Items: ${items}`);
    console.log('done');
}

async function test() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        balance = db.get('userInfo.balance'); // -> 1000
        items = db.get('userInfo.items'); // ['Sword', 'Watch']
    }
}
```

Does it address your question?